# What can cause hs_err_pid file not to be created on crash?

Tags: java, crash

I need to investigate crashes of a Java client application. It's s Swing application, running in Java Web Start environement on Java SE 6 Update 23 on Windows. Unfortunately for some crash cases the hs_err_pid file was not created. It wasn't on the desktop, so I've searched for it on PC and did not find it(there was an old hs_err_pid file on the desktop, for the same application, so it's reasonable to assume the new one should have been created there too). There is no exception in the log in the end, as it usually happens when JVM crashes on Java exception, so it looks like a crash that should result on creation of hs_err_pid file.

Do I need to configure something to make it work? Can the configuration of Dr. Watson affect the creation of hs_err_pid file?

Thanks

We configured Dr' Watson and analyzed the core dump file, which was created after the app crashed again. The error I saw was "Access violation". From the stack trace I was able to see that the crash is caused by exception in a native code of a third party we use. This was enough to delegate the issue to them.

Bottom line:
1. Some Java crashes are not handled as expected by JVM so that hs_err_pid file is not created.
2. Configuring OS to create a core dump can help in those cases, as the crash that is not handled by JVM will be handled by the OS. You'll get less information in this case, still it can be helpful.

Comment: JVM crashes on Java exception - what is the exception,can you paste the stack trace here , or the code .

Comment: @Suresh - he's trying to *find* the log output that will give him more details of the crash (including the exception trace, if any).

Comment: It won't write the file if the process has no access to the directory it would normally write it to.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey There is already old hs_err_pid file for our application on user's desktop, so the user has the access to the directory. Looks file is not created in some specific conditions

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am also having this issue. JVM crashes, there is a core dump, but no hs_err file. There is plenty of space in the working directory and write permissions (that's why the core dump files goes there.) The hs_err file gets generated only about 50% of the time.

Answer (score 8):

If the crash occurs as the result of a native stack overflow (typically resulting in a SIGSEGV as the application tries to read/write a stack guard page), no hs_err_pid file is generated on many platforms (e.g., Linux) since the process which creates the file cannot complete if you are out of stack space.

Comment: It wasn't the case of native stack overflow. We configured Dr' Watson and analyzed the core dump file. The error I saw was "Access violation".

Comment: Well access violation and stack overflow are not mutually exclusive.  What happens when a stack overflow occurs depends on the OS, runtime environment, how the overflow happens, etc.

Comment: For example, on Linux a stack overflow usually (often?) produces SIGSEV, which is equivalent to an access violation on Windows.  Other things, like a bad pointer access, can cause SIGSEV, but in these other cases the JVM is typically able to create an hs_err_pid file.

Answer (score 6):

Note that `hs_err_pid.log` files only get created if there is an actual JVM crash.

If your application "only" quits due to an unhandled exception somewhere, then no such file will be created.

Are you sure that the crash was a real JVM crash?

Comment: All unhandled exceptions are printed to the log. When the application quits with unhandled exception, we see it in the end of the log file, in this case there is no exception in the log.

Answer (score 3):

JDK 5 http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/jdk50_ts_guide.pdf

> ```
> When a fatal error occurs an error log is created in the file
> ```
>
> hs_err_pid.log (where  is
>   the process id of the process). Where
>   possible the file is created in the
>   working directory of the process. In
>   the event that the file cannot be
>   created in the working directory
>   (insufficient space, permission
>   problem, or other issue) then the file
>   is created in the temporary directory
>   for the operating system. On Solaris
>   and Linux the temporary directory is
>   /tmp. On Windows the temporary
>   directory is specified by the value of
>   the TMP environment variable, or if
>   that is not defined, the value of the
>   TEMP environment variable.

Comment: There is already old hs_err_pid file for our application on user's desktop (that's where the link to the application is, so that's the working directory), so the user has the access to the directory. Looks like the file is not created in some specific conditions